# Multiple answers from the same person to a question

Tags: discussion, answers

Recently, when answering [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/655/multiply-without-multiply) question, I devised two solutions, each with a different approach. Now my doubt, and the point of this question, is whether I should've posted both solutions under a same answer.

What should be the accepted practice for this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For code games, I'd say that if the solutions are distinct (different languages, different algorithmic approaches) that you *should* post them separately.

Answer (score 7):

I've used multiple answers many times when doing different languages. Less often for different algorithms, but I do not hesitate to do so if I believe both/all answers are interesting enough.

Nobody has complained thus far :)